# How to get the memory usage by bytes using script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script and I need to modify this so it can print the memory usage into the file with bytes.

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "$HOSTNAME, timestamp=$( date +%s ), free -b" >> "system_monitor.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your script should look like is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -e "$HOSTNAME, $(date +%s), \\n $(free -b)" >> "system_monitor.csv"
```

The `timestamp` variable is unnecessary in this case. And I would suggest adding two news line or one to make the output readable. So a better command would be:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

echo -e "$HOSTNAME, $(date +%s), \\n $(free -b) \\n \\n" >> "system_monitor.csv"
```